# Silly trouble with view and lists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, erb

I am with a silly problem with my view.

i am using the code:

```
<p>
  <b>Livros:</b>
  <ul>
    <% @orb.books.each do |book| %>
    <li> <% book.nome %> </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</p>
```

orbs has a many to many association with books.

When i test this, on a orb that have 2 books associated. it render 2 li elements, but they are empty; no book.name is printed. What i am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the rendering tag (the one with the equal sign):

```
<%= book.nome %>
```

Comment: Oh, thats the difference of <%, and <%= ! I dindt know. Many thanks

Comment: That's right! Don't forget to choose the answer as the correct one if it solved your problem. :)

Comment: It had limited me to check as right for 20 minutes. I was waiting :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<p>
  <b>Livros:</b>
  <ul>
    <% @orb.books.each do |book| %>
    <li> <%= book.nome %> </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</p>
```